# Segue won't change screens when clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create an app with multiple scenes the first two scenes connect and transition fine using a segue, but when i add a third scene and connect it with a segue nothing happens when i click the control to transition. Here is the code i have so far

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showStops"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.directionTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        StopsViewController *destViewController = (StopsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.routeNumber =[[feeds
                                          objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"rtNumber" ];
        destViewController.direction =[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Direction"];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your segue causing `prepareForSegue:` to fire? Maybe show your storyboard?

Comment: its not firing nothing happens

Comment: Gonna need to see how your storyboard is set up then.

Comment: Have you defined the identifier "showStops" in your storyboards?

Comment: Yes i have defined the indentifier

Answer (score 0):

So let me see if I got it. U have a screen that connect to two others screens right? So u need two Segues with differents identifier. Than in method prepareForSegue u will check wich one was clicked.

Something like this!

```
- (IBAction)firstConnection:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstSegue" sender:nil];
}

- (IBAction)secondConnection:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondSegue" sender:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstSegue"]){
        // YOUR TRANSITION
    }

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondSegue"]){
        // YOUR TRANSITION
    }
}
```